# PrestaShop Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8320 bytes) in smarty_internal_templatelexer.php

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7680 bytes) in /home/admin/web/original-peptide.com/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatelexer.php on line 473

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

look [here](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/251028-solved-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-exhausted/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

A support customer just modified a product from "normal" product to "pack", and added the same product as a variant of the new "pack", resulting in a endless loop, using up as much RAM as the system would allow.

Since the product page didn't open anymore neither in the backend and on the catalog page, we had to undo the "packing" via database.

```
delete from ps_pack where id_product_item=1;
delete from ps_pack where id_product_item=2;
update ps_product set cache_is_pack=0 where id_product=1;
update ps_product set cache_is_pack=0 where id_product=2;
```